# how to make a large ISO storage on xen cloud platform (XCP) or XenServer

Tags: linux, xen

i've downloaded XCP 1.5 beta from http://www.xen.org/download/xcp/index_1.5.0.html. i've managed to install it too. my physical system specifications are

```
3.01 GHz i7
24 GB Ram
3 TB HDD
```

now i would like to create an ISO storage space on the same physical server itself. i notice that Dom0 only has 4 GB of space, of which, 40% is in use. i need to create space elsewhere on my 3 TB HDD as an ISO storage area, how do i do this?

on Dom0, "df -h" gives me the following information.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             4.0G  1.5G  2.3G  40% /
none                  380M     0  380M   0% /dev/shm
```

"pvs" gives me the following output.

```
PV         VG                                                 Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
/dev/sda3  VG_XenStorage-5a32ce29-c98e-1488-273e-263c65d47479 lvm2 a-   2.72T 2.62T
```

there's a link here, http://www.riverlite.co.uk/2012/01/xenserver-creating-a-local-iso-library/, that describes this problem, however, i am lost in Part 2 - Creating a larger ISO library, because for some reason, he has some extra file systems (that i don't see on my own system).

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume that you haven`t created logical volume which will be used as storage for ISO images. For example, to create 100GB logical volume called ISO_Storage issue:

```
lvcreate -L100G -n /dev/VG_XenStorage-5a32ce29-c98e-1488-273e-263c65d47479/ISO_Storage
```

Having done this we need to format it:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/VG_XenStorage-5a32ce29-c98e-1488-273e-263c65d47479/ISO_Storage
```

Create target directory and mount volume into it:

```
mkdir -p /home/ISO_Storage
mount /dev/VG_XenStorage-5a32ce29-c98e-1488-273e-263c65d47479/ISO_Storage /home/ISO_Storage
```